# Change background color of row on item drop draglistview android

Tags: android, listview, drag-and-drop, listviewitem

I'm using
[this](https://github.com/woxblom/DragListView) DragListView in my application. I want to change the background color of a row once it is in correct position in the list view. How can I achieve this? This is a code snippet of what I have so far:

```
public void checkOrderOfProcedures(){
    mItemArray = new ArrayList<>();
    mDragListView.setDragListListener(new DragListView.DragListListenerAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void onItemDragStarted(int position) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onItemDragEnded(int fromPosition, final int toPosition) {
            if (Long.valueOf(toPosition).equals((Long)(mItemArray.get(toPosition).first))) {
                Toast.makeText(mDragListView.getContext(), "Correct position", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                class MyDragItem extends DragItem {
                    public MyDragItem(Context context, int layoutId) {
                        super(context, layoutId);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onBindDragView(View clickedView, View dragView) {
                        CharSequence text = ((TextView) clickedView.findViewById(R.id.text)).getText();
                        ((TextView) dragView.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(text);
                        dragView.setBackgroundColor(dragView.getResources().getColor(R.color.dialogRightBackground));
                    }
                }

                //change background color of the row (correct position) to green
                //disable drag of a row if it is in correct position
                mDragListView.setDragListCallback(new DragListView.DragListCallbackAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean canDragItemAtPosition(int dragPosition) {
                        return dragPosition != mItemArray.get(toPosition).first;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public boolean canDropItemAtPosition(int dropPosition) {
                        return dropPosition != mItemArray.get(toPosition).first;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mDragListView.getContext(), "Incorrect position", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    setupListRecyclerView();
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private static class MyDragItem extends DragItem {
    public MyDragItem(Context context, int layoutId) {
        super(context, layoutId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindDragView(View clickedView, View dragView) {
        CharSequence text = ((TextView) clickedView.findViewById(R.id.text)).getText();
        ((TextView) dragView.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText(text);
        dragView.setBackgroundColor(dragView.getResources().getColor(R.color.list_item_background));
    }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated thanks!